# error in INNER JOIN statement

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I'm trying to write an `INNER JOIN` query. I wanted to get rows/information that are in two different tables. Here's what I'm trying:

Table Names are: Students and main_table

```
$sql =mysql_query ("SELECT main_table.maric_no, main_table.academic_session, main_table.semester, 
main_table.course_name, main_table.total, students.first_name, students.last_name, 
students.other_name, students.level 
FROM main_table INNER JOIN students ON 
main_table.matric_no = students.matric_no 
WHERE main_table.matric = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[matric_no]'"); 

$number_cols = mysql_num_fields($sql);
```

Here's the error message:

```
ERROR: mysql_num_fields() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in c:\filepath on line Number..
```

Where could the problem be coming from?

Comment: Your error seems to be coming from incorrect usage of [mysql_num_fields](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-fields.php). I think what you really want is [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: i have edited the code to include mysql_query at the first SELECT statement.

Comment: Always add `or die( mysql_error() )` to the end of the query to find out if you have errors.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of an issue you already reported:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162901/inner-join-statement-error/9162971

Comment: could you output the results of mysql_error() immediately following your mysql_num_fields call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors at first glance:

1. [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is a php function, not a mysql-function. It is used to make data safer before using it in a mysql-query.
2. Your $_POST-variable isn't assigned properly.

Format it like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("
    SELECT M.maric_no, M.academic_session,  
        M.semester, M.course_name, M.total, 
        S.first_name, S.last_name, 
        S.other_name, S.level 
    FROM main_table M 
    INNER JOIN students S ON M.matric_no = S.matric_no 
    WHERE M.matric = '"
    .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['matric_no'])
    ."'");
```

I took the liberty to add aliases to the table names, this cleans up your SQL statement quite a lot.

There might be other errors, too (p.e. wrong fields, is your WHERE-statement really on the field `main_table.matric` and not `main_table.matric_no`?), but in order to analyze this you'll need to provide more details about your tables.

Answer (score 4):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-fields.php

You need to pass a query result to `mysql_num_fields`, not a SQL string. Try:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$number_cols = mysql_num_fields($res);
```

Comment: I have run the query first. But i'm still getting the same error. Thanks

Comment: how come it received a plus vote when it did not even state that the error is on the sql query string?

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query` returns false if there is an error, thus the boolean result and not a resource.
try this

```
$sql =mysql_query ("SELECT main_table.maric_no, main_table.academic_session, main_table.semester, 
main_table.course_name, main_table.total, students.first_name, students.last_name, 
students.other_name, students.level 
FROM main_table INNER JOIN students ON 
main_table.matric_no = students.matric_no 
WHERE main_table.matric = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[matric_no])."'");
```

Comment: yes i know, but where is the problem coming from? Is it the stucture of the query or what? I'm i not using the INNER JOIN.......ON......WHERE correctly?

Comment: @KanyinsolaOyesanmi: `mysql_real_escape_string` is a PHP function and can't be inside the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[matric_no]
```

You can't use a function call like that inside a double quoted string.

```
"WHERE main_table.matric = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[matric_no]) . "'");
```

It should look like:

```
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT main_table.maric_no, main_table.academic_session, main_table.semester, 
main_table.course_name, main_table.total, students.first_name, students.last_name, 
students.other_name, students.level 
FROM main_table INNER JOIN students ON 
main_table.matric_no = students.matric_no 
WHERE main_table.matric = ". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[matric_no]) . "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query()` returns Boolean `False` when it fails with an error. Since there is an error in your SQL, `$sql` equals `False`.

`mysql_num_fields()` expects you to pass in a result set, not a Boolean value, hence the error: `ERROR: mysql_num_fields() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`.

You are including `mysql_real_escape_string()`, which is a PHP function, directly in the query. Instead of this:

```
"WHERE main_table.matric = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[matric_no]'");"
```

Try something more like this, assuming `matric` is a number:

```
"WHERE main_table.matric = ". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[matric_no]);
```

Use `mysql_error()` function in PHP to see what MySQL says your error in the SQL is.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run the query first.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num_cols = mysql_num_fields($result);
```

Comment: I did but still showing the same problem.

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump($result);`?